# Malloc sizeof individual members of a struct?

Tags: c, memory, struct, malloc

So I looked for malloc of individual members of a struct but only found a simple example of double a, int b, then sizeof(a + b). I'm trying to do a similar effort with chars from a struct but cannot figure out how this works. From online resources I need to do a comma between the variables rather than + due to it being chars though its not very clear. I could just malloc the entire size of the struct but that's not the intended goal. I'm optimizing space.

File 1

```
typedef struct _TeamInfo_s {
        char        name[MAXNAME];
        char        nickname[MAXNICKNAME];
        MLSconf_t   conf;
        float       ppg;
        int         pts;
        int         gp;
        int         win;
        int         loss;
        int         tie;
    } TeamInfo_t, *TeamInfoPtr_t;
```

and in file 2 for malloc

```
char* createKey(TeamInfoPtr_t teamInfoPtr) {
    //TODO:  WRITE THIS FUNCTION
    char* name = malloc(sizeof(TeamInfo_t.nickname,TeamInfo_t.name));
    //Extra code here for setting name
    return name;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Do you want to know the size of name and nickname together?

Comment: "malloc of individual members of a struct": you can't do that. All members are contiguous. You can't allocate a part of a struct... unless you don't read or write the last members, in which case I suggest you don't _declare_ those members

Comment: if you're optimizing space, declare pointers instead of arrays, to adjust the names to the actual names

Comment: `sizeof` is an unary operator. You can't pass to it two parameters like in `sizeof(TeamInfo_t.nickname,TeamInfo_t.name)`. Maybe you want the total size? Something like `sizeof(team.nickname) +sizeof (team.name)`?

Comment: You _can_ do: `sizeof(Teaminfo_t)`. But ... You can _not_ do: `sizeof(TeamInfo_t.name)` because `TeamInfo_t` is a `typedef` (i.e. a _type_). And, `sizeof` can only take one arg. So, you need a concrete variable. How about: `TeamInfo_t myteam; char* name = malloc(sizeof(myteam.nickname) + sizeof(myteam.name));`

Comment: I'm trying to create a pointer with sizeof the name and nickname together. I could do sizeof(teaminfo_t) but I want to only allocate space for two of the members being the char name, and char nickname. I don't want to hardcode sizeof(char + char) either. I assumed I could use the variable names teaminfo_t.name and teaminfo_t.nickname and it would convert into sizeof(char + char).

Comment: The output of my function is to be a pointer to a combined name+nickname so I'm trying to allocate space, then set the char* name equal to the values together and return it.

Comment: You have defines for your array lengths, so why don't you use `char *name = malloc(MAXNAME+MAXNICKNAME);`?

Comment: Why don't you just do `malloc (MAXNAME+MAXNICKNAME);`?

Comment: So char *name = malloc(MAXNAME+MAXNICKNAME) isn't possible because I need to use the char and theres no maxname or maxnickname defined. I don't understand how sizeof only takes one input value but there are examples where they add a float and a double together... Is that just because you can add floats and doubles whereas chars can't?

Comment: If there is no MAXNAME or MAXNICKNAME defined then why did you say there was?

Comment: Well its the name of the array quantity but it's the sizeof char type in the typedef.

Comment: *I could just malloc the entire size of the struct but that's not the intended goal. I'm optimizing space*  Why are you optimizing space?  Are you running out of memory when running your process?  Are you using so much memory other processes are having problems getting memory to run?  If you're not running into any of those problems, the only reason to do what you're doing is to practice - and it's really easy to practice **not** allocating memory.  There are many ways to do that - like posting comments on Stackoverflow...

Comment: Andrew don't worry about why I'm optimizing space. That's not the point. Part of it is understanding more to how sizeof works rather than the brief example from K&R and why my statement's not working. I'm trying to figure out this task to return the pointer to a key value of name and nickname combined together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to create a buffer to store a combination of both `nickname` and `name` (plus I'm assuming a space between the two), you'd do something like this:

```
char *name = malloc( sizeof teamInfoPtr->nickname + 
                     sizeof teamInfoPtr->name + 
                     1 + // for space between nickname and name 
                     1   // for string terminator
             );
sprintf( name, "%s %s", teamInfoPtr->nickname, teamInfoPtr->name );
```

If `MAXNICKNAME` and `MAXNAME` each already account for the string terminator, then you probably don't need to add 1 for it above.  You *do* need to account for the extra space (or any other extra characters) in the combined name.

The type of the *expression* `teamInfoPtr->nickname` is `char [MAXNICKNAME]`, so `sizeof teamInfoPtr->nickname` is equivalent to `sizeof (char [MAXNICKNAME])`.  Same reasoning applies to `sizeof teamInfoPtr->name`.  Remember that `sizeof` is an operator, not a function - the only time you need to use parentheses is when the operand is a type name.  Of course, you can use parentheses when the operand is an expression, you just don't *need* to.

Because they are operands to the `sizeof` operator, the expressions `teamInfoPtr->nickname` and `teamInfoPtr->name` *don't* "decay" to type `char *`.

Comment: Thanks John, that's close to what I'm looking for and excellent explanations. I didn't know sizeof was just an operator and I didn't know about the type name requirement though I've only been using that before. I thought the teamInfoPtr->name is the type char because name is declared as a char type?

Comment: @AlB: `name` and `nickname` are declared as *arrays* of `char` type, which are distinct types in and of themselves (i.e., `char` is a distinct type from `char [10]`, which is a distinct type from `char [20]`, etc.).

Comment: to optimize memory it would be better to use `strlen` on the inputs, so `name` has the exact required size, not more

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, try this:

```
typedef struct _TeamInfo_s {
        char        *name;
        char        *nickname;
        MLSconf_t   conf;
        float       ppg;
        int         pts;
        int         gp;
        int         win;
        int         loss;
        int         tie;
    } TeamInfo_t, *TeamInfoPtr_t;

TeamInfo_t ti;

ti.name = malloc(MAXNAME);         // or whatever size you want
ti.nickname = malloc(MAXNICKNAME); // or whatever size you want
```